# Rails 4 sass application file doesn't read in css file imported

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

This is my application.css.sass :

```
@import "global.css.sass"
@import "bootstrap.css"
```

When I look at the source at my localhost `application.css?body=1` I see this:

```
@import url(bootstrap.css);

    #content-wrap {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto; }
```

So the global.css.sass contains this :

```
#content-wrap
  width: 90%
  margin: 0 auto
```

So that was imported appropriately, but not bootstrap.css file. And it works on the localhost because its on the file path locally. However in production my assets are on aws:

```
application-a0546f0315a891e8129e1f8e49eb7e45.css
```

When looking at source the content is the same as on my localhost, however there is not bootstrap on the path so that file is missing, and I wonder why isn't it all bundled in all one big application file, here are my assets related config.

Development :

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.digest = false
```

Production :

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated

**Update :**

This is sample bit from my chrome console :

```
Request URL:http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/bootstrap.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 Forbidden
```

Comment: [Have a look in the sass docu](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) `@import takes a filename to import. By default, it looks for a Sass file to import directly, but there are a few circumstances under which it will compile to a CSS @import rule`. Do you get any 404 on your console by any chance? I think the bootstrap.css is not beeing published in your productive environment. The lazy solution would be to refactor to `bootstrap.scss` and let it be merged into your `application.css`

Comment: @NicoO Thanks for your response. Yes I get 403 error. Regardless of error type the file bootstrap.css is not on the AWS. `I think the bootstrap.css is not beeing published in your productive environment` Yes this is true. Not sure why it isn't being bundled into my `application.css`

Comment: Because of the extention `.css`. You use a classic css [import](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#at-ruledef-import) which is unequal to the sass [`@import`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) function. Rename the bootstrap.css to bootstrap.scss (in the file and in the import) and it should work.

Comment: nice make this an answer i'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the [SCSS Documentation, that explains the  @import function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) from SCSS.

> @import takes a filename to import. By default, it looks for a Sass
>   file to import directly, but there are a few circumstances under which
>   it will compile to a CSS @import rule:
>
> - **If the files extension is .css.**
> - If the filename begins with http://.
> - If the filename is a url().
> - If the @import has any media queries

It's important to see the difference between the usge of [`@import` rule from css](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#at-ruledef-import) and the `@import` given by SCSS.

When you write this in your **scss** file:

```
@import "somefile.css"
```

The file `somefile.css` **will not be merged within your scss compiled file**. SASS will just compile this to the css @import rule, causing a http request to look for `somefile.css` on your server.

You can either want this, and upload `somefile.css` to the server under the correct path, or you just rename `somefile.css` to `somefile.scss` and change the import to `@import "somefile.scss"`. Like this SASS will merge `somefile.scss` to the compiled file.